# How to manage two X-axes with two correlated data columns?

Tags: r

I try to have two axis : Axis-1 (below) and Axis-3 (above) with two correlated data columns. Unfortunately, I have problems with my third axis. Indeed, for each data line, there is a tick. This is due because the parameter "at" in the axis () function is inquired.

Is there a way to create the axes relative to the other?

My data :

```
| NbConsumer | NbProvider | 
|------------|------------| 
| 10         | 5          | 
| 110        | 85         | 
| 210        | 165        | 
| 310        | 245        | 
| 410        | 325        |
```

Below an image of my plot :

[Plot Image with axes](https://i.stack.imgur.com/b1ZXA.png)

My source code :

```
  plot(x=c(min(x),max(x)),y=c(min(yMin),max(yMax)),type="n", xlab=xlab,ylab=ylab)
  axis(side=3, at=c(xThree), labels=xThreeLab)
  #axis(side=3, at=seq(5,3000,by=100), labels = c(0,100,200))

  title(main="Round Robin Mean Execution Time", col.main="black", font.main=4, line=3)
  mtext("Number of Provider", side=3, line=2)
  grid(col="black")
```

Where xThree=dataresult$NbConsumer, xThreeLab=dataresult$NbProvider

Thank you in advance.

Comment: What do you mean by "create the axes relative to the other" ? What's wrong with `axis(3, ...)` lines. By the way, having 2 different scales is always confusing (perhaps even more on the x- than on the y-axis).

Comment: Hi, Thank you for your response.

I just want to say that the number of provider should be displayed identically to the number of consumer. Clearly, the only problem is the number of tick which appears on the X-axis 3. I wish it only prints some taking naturally into account the labels of the column "NbProvider". 

Is it possible, with R, get values at regular intervals in a column? Because I could use seq with parameters "at" and "labels", no ?

Thank you

Comment: axes ticks are calculated using `pretty` but you can constraint them using `seq` indeed ;-)

Comment: Thank you vincent. Do you know a method or R function for split my data frame with row at regular interval. Example : I want splitmy data frame like that (i divide by 3 (5mod3) ) : 10; 110; 210; 310;410 become 110;310. i wrote this : test<-split(x3, factor(nrow(x3)%%3)) but doesn't work. have you an idea for me ? Thanks.

Comment: I don't understand what you want to do, but with `seq`, `rep`, `pretty`, `cut`, you can do pretty much everything related to intervals and regular sequences.